# Unable to invoke multiple browsers using JSTestDriver

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Hi 
The JSTestDriver documentation say...

"Multiple browsers can be specified if separated by a comma ','. 
java -jar JsTestDriver.jar --port 9876 --browser firefoxpath,chromepath"

So far I can only open one browser. Lets say if I want to open IE and Chrome, the below command only opens IE.

C:\libs>java -jar JsTestDriver.jar --port 9876 --browser "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe, C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I think you need to add quotes between iexplore and chrome? ie `C:\libs>java -jar JsTestDriver.jar --port 9876 --browser "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe","C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

Comment: I tried that, but it only opens the IE. Then gives me the error...

Comment: Exception SyntaxError: Expected ')'

Answer (score 0):

have you try using the `--captureConsole` flag, so it'd look like this:

`C:\libs>java -jar JsTestDriver.jar --port 9876 --browser "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe, C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --captureConsole`

Keep in mind that in JSTD version 1.3.1 this does not seem to work ( http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/issues/detail?id=199&q=browser%20capture )...
But in 1.2.2 that should work